# How to change position of ImageButton in Android

Tags: android, position

How can I change the position of ImageButton when I click on it.

[image]

There are 6 ImageButton here: `ibWolf1, ibWolf2, ibWolf3, ibSheep1, ibSheep2, ibSheep3;` 1 ImageView `ivWood` and 1 Button `btnGoAndBack`. When I click ibSheep3, `ibSheep3` will change position like this:

[image]

And when I continue to click on ibWolf3 it will change position like this:

[image]

That means the image will appear above the wood image. So how to do this?

Here is my game_play_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:background="#3300FF00"
        android:id="@+id/btnGoAndBack"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivWood"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ibSheep2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ibSheep2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wolf"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/ibWolf1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ibSheep2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wolf"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/ibWolf2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ibWolf1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wolf"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/ibWolf3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ibWolf2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sheep"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/ibSheep1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ibWolf2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ibWolf1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ibWolf1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sheep"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/ibSheep2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ibWolf2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ibWolf2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sheep"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/ibSheep3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ibSheep2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ibWolf3"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ibWolf3" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wood"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/ivWood"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ibSheep2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ibSheep2"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is that,put two images of sheep and wolf above go button and at first make the visibility invisible or gone.Now when user clicks on the sheep or the wolf images make the visibility of the imagebutton gone and make the image visible of the image above go button.

Otherwise you have to calculate the position of the go button and create a imagebutton  progmatically and place it over there.

Hope it clears your view.

Comment: So I have to add 2 more ImageButton above the wood ImageView. But this way is very hard to handle the project.

Comment: Yeap,but I don't think it will be hard to handle.Why do you think that?All you have to check the listener of the button

Comment: I want to create a game that give all 6 these animals to cross the river, each time when the amount of wolfs > amount of sheeps --> GAMEOVER. I will try your way first, but I need some ways better.

Comment: Got it. Let's see if anyone have some better way. Calculating all the position would be harder than what i have suggested.Good luck.

Comment: If we use translation, I think it doesn't run actually in different devices.

Comment: No it should run.You can try atleast and see what's the output.

Comment: I means how to translation it to appear above the wood image